# Missing data(modbus) in the socket data received

Tags: python, sockets, modbus

I am sending a modbus data over a socket client tool. I have written a small server program to receive the incoming data. the data(hex) which I receive in the socket test tool is as expected. But, the data I receive in the program is some garbage data.

program data ([ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Rka.png)):

```
...
RECIEVED: Wed Sep 19 16:34:25 2018 b'\x01\x04\x04Cgq\xc0{\xdf'
```

Software data ([ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BEr9.png)):

```
01 04 04 43 67 71 c0 7b df


  import socket

    client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    ip = '192.168.10.3'
    port = 4196
    address = (ip,port)
    client.connect(address)
    print("connected")
    datasent = client.send(b"\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x71\xcb")
    print(datasent)
    data= client.recv(1024)
    print(" ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in (data)))
```

Comment: By the way, in future, please copy the *text* output from your tool and paste it directly into the question. Screenshot images are very inconvenient for readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the exact same bytes. They're just being displayed differently. The python interpreter displays byte values as an ASCII character when possible. That is, hex bytes `43 67 71` are the ASCII characters 'Cgq', and so forth. Python only shows `\xNN` format for non-ASCII characters.

Instead of just `print`ing `str(data)`, try this to make it look similar:

```
print("RECEIVED:", time.ctime(), " ".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in data))
```

Comment: what if I want to call the register using python. will this format work??          
Request to the server: client_socket.send(("01 04 00 00 00 02 71 CB").encode())

Comment: @Nithya No; that byte sequence will not work. Modbus is a binary protocol. You need to convert your string (which is the ASCII encoding of the hexadecimal digits) into the corresponding binary: `b"\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x71\xcb"`

Comment: Or if you really want to start from the character string, you can convert it like this: `bytes(int(x, 16) for x in "01 04 00 00 00 02 71 CB".encode().split())`

Comment: for both the code the datasent prints 8, I think I went wrong somewhere. please correct me . Added the code in the question. thanks

Comment: it worked. Might be my device communication was interrupted. thanks Gil

Comment: do you have any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553273/oserror-winerror-10056-a-connect-request-was-made-on-an-already-connected-soc  please let me know if it can be resolved