# OSError: [WinError 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I want to make the connection automated. Facing the below issue while running the code. tried adding disconnect but it didn't work. The system is getting connected and data is being transferred. once the connection is lost and when the system tries to reconnect I am facing the issue.

```
import socket,time
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
ip = '192.168.xx.x'
port = 4xxx
address = (ip,port)

def connect():
    try:
        while 1:
            print("connecting")
            try:
                client.connect(address)
                print("connected")
            except TimeoutError:
                print("wait for few mins")
                time.sleep(20)
                connect()
            break
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        print("connection aborted wait for few sec")
        time.sleep(10)
        connect()    

connect()    
try:
    while 1:
        datasent = client.send(b'\x01\x04')
        if datasent:
            print("sent")
            data= client.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            time.sleep(5)
        if  not datasent:
            connect()


except ConnectionResetError:
    client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    client.close()
    print("wait for 10 sec")
    time.sleep(10)
    connect()



    >Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\ckeck\client.py", line 28, in <module>
    datasent = client.send(b'\x01\x04\') 
    ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\ckeck\client.py", line 41, in <module>
    connect()
    File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\ckeck\client.py", line 13, in connect
    client.connect(address)
    OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: You are connecting in a while loop, which will make it connect non stop, hence the error. You connect first, it works and you connect again and again (except that it throws an error). Try removing the while loop you will see if it happens if you only connect once.

Comment: I am facing the issue while the connection is lost and the system tries to reconnect. The while loop here make sure that the system is connected back. I guess removing the while loop here is not going to solve my problem. added the complete error in the code, Please check